# Gcc: Accessing and initializing unions and bitfields within struct

Tags: c, gcc, struct, unions, bit-fields

I have a struct that consists of a union, a variable and a bitfield:

```
typedef struct router_client {
    union {
        QHsm  *client;
        void (*handler)(QSignal sig, QParam par);
    };
    uint8_t level;
    struct {
        uint8_t presence:2;
        uint8_t is_hsm:1;
        uint8_t is_handler:1;
    };
} router_client_t;
```

What is the proper way to initialize it? I used to

```
router_client_t = {.client=(QHsm*)&qhsm_foo, level = l, \
.presence = p, .is_hsm = s, .is_handler = a}
```

But when switching toolchain from Code Red MCU tools to Cross GCC I started getting

```
unknown field 'client' specified in initializer
unknown field 'presence' specified in initializer
...
```

The point of the union is that I want to be able to assign values either to client or handler and let them share the same pointer.
I tried a few things and I know I can change the struct but I just wanted to know if there is a C99 way of initializing and accessing it.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it stems from using an unnamed union ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can work. I think that the trick is name of structs and union.

```
typedef union {
    int  *client;
    void (*handler)(int sig, int par);
}union_t;

typedef struct {
    uint8_t presence:2;
    uint8_t is_hsm:1;
    uint8_t is_handler:1;
}struct_t;

typedef struct router_client {
    union_t test;
    uint8_t level;
    struct_t test2
} router_client_t;

void main()
{
    int pippo;
    router_client_t pippo2= {.test.client=(int*)&pippo, .level = 10, .test2.presence = 2, .test2.is_hsm = 1, .test2.is_handler = 1};
}
```

Or as you wrote:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct router_client {
    union{
        int  *client;
        void (*handler)(int sig, int par);
    }union_t;
    uint8_t level;
    struct {
        uint8_t presence:2;
        uint8_t is_hsm:1;
        uint8_t is_handler:1;
    }struct_t;
} router_client_t;

void main()
{
    int pippo;
    router_client_t pippo2= {.union_t.client=(int*)&pippo, .level = 10, .struct_t.presence = 2, .struct_t.is_hsm = 1, .struct_t.is_handler = 1};
}
```

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that this compiles with both toolchains

Answer (score 2):

I see an unnamed struct and an unnamed union.

It is highly probably that the cross gcc compiler is not handling anonymous structs and unions with what ever the default standard is.

suggest adding an appropriate parameter to the compile, something like

```
'-std=c11'
```

Comment: Already -std=c99 is in use. But the problem was indeed the unnamed struct and union, solvable as in LPs answer. Thanks.